# Deriving Power Budget for SAMA5D27C from Datasheet

Tags: power-supply, buck, microchip, mpu

I am spec'ing out my power distribution network and trying to figure out what Buck converters I am going to need for a Microchip MPU design using SAMA5D27C. I am looking through the data sheet below for the SAMA5D27C. It gives clear information about expected voltage level for the power rails VDDCORE, VDDPLLA, VDDUTMIC, VDDHSIC, VDDIODDR, VDDIOP0, VDDIOP1, VDDIOP2, VDDISC, VDDSDMMC, VDDUTMII, VDDOSC, VDDAUDIOPLL, VDDANA, VDDFUSE, and VDDBU.

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPU-SAMA5D27C-CNVAO-datasheet-60001532a.pdf

I am trying to estimate the load current I will require for each voltage supply. The datasheet does not seem to directly outline this datapoint. I was wondering if this is normally in datahseets or if I am missing something obvious in this particular datasheet.

There are some metrics under "67. Electrical Characteristics" about current drawn from particular peripherals but the mappings of these peripherals to the voltage supply isn't always clear. EG if you look at section 67.5.1 for the main oscillator, at table 67-11 you see Iddon current consumption is said to be on VDDIO which is bizarre given there is a VDDOSC power supply.

Was wondering if anyone ever worked with Microchip MPUs and has any idea how to perform a power budget/spec out Buck converters from their datasheets.

Comment: I also cannot find power consumption data for active mode in the datasheet. There is a funny typo in table 67-2 claiming maximum total power dissipation is 575 W.

Comment: One of the reasons I was posting this. That really freaked me out, seemed out of place. Thinking "which power source is consuming that much current"? It is an automotive chip but still that seems like an unrealistic estimation

Comment: @Jens what do you think it actually should be? 5.75W?

Comment: Sounds plausible to me, it would desolder itself and leave the board on more power :)